# import { LiveChatWidget } from "@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-widget"; How can we initiate the chat in LiveChatWidget programmatically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to customize the LiveChatWidget [@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-widget](https://github.com/microsoft/omnichannel-chat-widget). But when I add the onSubmit function that is derived from preChatSurveyPaneProps -> controlProps -> onSubmit to validate the input fields of preChatSurveyPane, the liveCHateWidget is not initiating the chat when I click on submit.

```
import { OmnichannelChatSDK } from "@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-sdk";
import { LiveChatWidget } from "@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-widget";
import {
  InputValidationPane,
  ChatButton,
  PreChatSurveyPane,
} from "@microsoft/omnichannel-chat-components";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const getOmnichannelChatConfig = () => {
  const omnichannelConfig = {
    orgId: "xxx", 
    orgUrl: "https://example.com", 
    widgetId: "xxx", 
  };
  return omnichannelConfig;
};

const ChatWidgetV1 = () => {
  const [liveChatWidgetProps, setLiveChatWidgetProps] = useState(null);

  const init = async () => {
    const omnichannelConfig = getOmnichannelChatConfig();
    const chatSDK = new OmnichannelChatSDK(omnichannelConfig);
    await chatSDK.initialize();
    const chatConfig = await chatSDK.getLiveChatConfig();

    const liveChatWidgetProps = {
      styleProps: {
        generalStyles: {
          width: "400px",
          height: "600px",
          bottom: "30px",
          right: "30px",
        },
      },
      chatSDK,
      chatConfig,
      webChatContainerProps: {
        disableMarkdownMessageFormatting: false,
      },
    };
    setLiveChatWidgetProps(liveChatWidgetProps);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  

  return (
    <div>
      {liveChatWidgetProps && (
        <LiveChatWidget
          {...liveChatWidgetProps}
          preChatSurveyPaneProps={{
            controlProps: {
              onSubmit: async (values) => {
                try {
                  console.log("values", values);
                } catch (error) {
                  console.log("CustomError", error);
                }
              },
            },
          }}
        ></LiveChatWidget>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ChatWidgetV1;
```

if i remove the **onSubmit** function from **LiveChatWidget** props that is drived preChatSurveyPaneProps -> controlProps -> onSubmit, click on submit button in **LiveChatWidget** , chat inititated successfully.

[image]

[image]

I want to initiate a new chat when I click on submit button,
when i click on submit, I need to validate the form input values if the values are fine then send these values and initiated a new chat through those values. But i didn't find any solution on how to trigger a new chat in onSubmite function.